# Aliasing a referenced relationship field in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

In the Mongoid model below, how do I alias the `belongs_to` relationship field?

```
class Contact
  field :nm, :as => :name, :type => String # field aliasing
  embeds_one :address, :store_as => :ad  # embedded document aliasing
  belongs_to :account # referenced relation doesn't support store_as
end
```

I want to store the account id in a field called `ac` instead of `account_id`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use :foreign_key to specify the mongodb field name.

```
belongs_to :account, foreign_key: :ac
```

However, if you want to use account_id, you need to declare its alias:

```
alias :account_id :ac
```

or defining account_id before belongs_to:

```
field :account_id, as: :ac
```

Comment: The `foreign_key` needs to be set on both sides of the relation.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoid allows to use arbitrary name for a relationship by using of 'inverse_of'

> If an inverse is not required, like a belongs_to or has_and_belongs_to_many, ensure that :inverse_of => nil is set on the
>   relation. If the inverse is needed, most likely the inverse cannot be
>   figured out from the names of the relations and you will need to
>   explicitly tell Mongoid on the relation what the inverse is.

So, for use 'ac' as an alias it's necessary to add `inverse_of`:

```
class Contact
  field :nm, :as => :name, :type => String # field aliasing
  embeds_one :address, :store_as => :ad  # embedded document aliasing
  belongs_to :ac, class_name: 'Account', inverse_of: :contact
end

class Account
  has_one :contact, class_name: 'Contact', inverse_of: :ac
end
```

Comment: This doesn't address my problem. I want to refer to the Account field as `account` instead of `ac`, hence the need for the alias feature.

Comment: You want to address by conact.ac and contact.account at once? Explain, please.

Comment: Mongoid library provides a feature for aliasing field names. This is quite useful when you are dealing with large sized collections. Essentially, if you look at the first scenario in my question, I store name as `nm` in the collection but access/query it as `name`. This feature works for regular fields and embedded associations. For referenced association there is no documented way to set this option.